# Rotating background picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm becoming desperate.. i try to build a site with a rotating background image, that automatically adjusts to the size of the window. i'm not really that much into html, css, javascript etc, but i managed to get so far, that the picture rotates and adjusts to the windows size.. BUT when i scale the window really small, the picture rotates out of the window.. i hope you understand what i mean.

This is my code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XE5xm/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="bgcon">
    <div id="bgimg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#bgcon {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bgimg {
    content:"";
    position: fixed;
    width: 250%;
    height: 250%;
    top: -80%;
    left: -80%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image: url("http://sidekickwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/space-wallpapers-1920x1080-design-ideas-space-wallpapers-s3vgbbit.jpg");
    -webkit-animation:spin 150s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 150s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 150s linear infinite;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
}
```

and this is the problem:
[image: Glitch]

i'm not sure if it's possible to create it with only css, but like i said, im not really into it much.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to set the element's size based on the largest dimension (width or height)

Comment: you mean the width/height in #bgimg?

Comment: hmm.. sorry to ask, but where should i write that. i'm really in my beginnings. the values of the image size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the width & height of `bgcon` to a higher proportion of the max value of the window's width and height, keeping it square:

```
var bg = document.getElementById("bgimg");

window.onresize = function() { 
    /* Compare values and set width/height based on higher value */ 
    var max = Math.max(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    bg.style.width = 2.5*max + "px";
    bg.style.height = 2.5*max + "px";
    bg.style.marginTop = -1.25*max + "px"; // Half of width/height
    bg.style.marginLeft = -1.25*max + "px"; // Half of width/height
}
window.onresize(); // Run on load
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bgimg"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
#bgimg {
    position:fixed;
    /* Center element on page */
    top:50%; left:50%;
    /* You have to center the image using center center */
    background: url("http://sidekickwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/space-wallpapers-1920x1080-design-ideas-space-wallpapers-s3vgbbit.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    animation:spin 150s linear infinite;
    transform-origin:center center; /* Makes it rotate about the center */
    /* Others */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XE5xm/10/)

The reason why the demo above is not perfect in large browsers is because the image is too small. To counteract that you could remove the `no-repeat` on the image and it will repeat itself until the space it taken. Or you could use a larger image. [**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XE5xm/9/) with a larger, different image showing it working correctly

Comment: i'll try that, give me some time :)

Comment: Ok, lets see.. the picture i use has a size of square (768x768px), i removed the no-repeat. Where should i know the max value of the window, cause it should run on different sizes? the /* Compare values and set width/height based on higher value */ confuses me :/ thanks for your help

Comment: @user3524991 `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` get the width and height of your current window. The code Zach posted should already work as it is. I would point out that the *shortest* side of your image needs to be larger than the *diagonal* distance from corner to corner of the window, or you'll still see light in the corners as it rotates. 250% should cover that in all but the most extreme cases, but is probably overkill for most windows.

Comment: actually i tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/8mJ6B/ with a small picture, but in the file on my pc, its not working. i dont understand why.. only if i add a height & width to #bgimg in my css file, you can see the picture.. i added the js in the <head><script> and the body only contains the <div> everything else is exactly the same as in the fiddle..

Answer (score -3):

I made this little guy for a personal project. Just put the image URL's in the array and change the selector to populate the background image. You may also need a little additional css to cover the background with the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = ['imageURL', 'imageUrl'],
        i = 0,
        timeoutVar;

    function changeBackground() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutVar); // just to be sure it will run only once at a time

        $('.YourSelector').css('background-image', function() {
            if (i >= images.length) {
                i=0;
            }
            return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';      
        });

        // call the setTimeout every time to repeat the function
        timeoutVar = setTimeout(changeBackground, 3000);
    }

    // Call it
    setTimeout(changeBackground() , 5000);

});
```

EDIT :

With some CSS you can make the background image "cover" background.

```
html { 
  background: url() no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Taken from :
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Working FIDDLE : 
http://jsfiddle.net/df9A2/

Hope this helps!

Comment: @zachSaucier "build a site with a rotating background image". I didn't create a slideshow. It's a function that takes a selector. All he would need to do is use the body as the selector and it would solve his issue.

Comment: you mean add it to my code in the html code and replace the imageURL?

Comment: yes. I just made an edit with some additional css to help you with the covering the entire background with the image as well. @ZachSaucier , thats funny because he specifically says "i try to build a site with a rotating background image". Keyword : rotating.

Comment: Let's make this clear: **Your solution has no rotation involved**

Comment: Any by the way, what you have is possible with using only CSS, no javascript or jQuery is necessary

Comment: Now use a non-square image and rotate it via CSS.  It now doesn't work.

Comment: @zachSaucier - It actually does have rotation. See fiddle.(in edit) But I guess I read the question to fast and didn't read his css well enough to see that he was after a literal rotating (spin) background image. My bad. I was thinking he was loosely using the term to mean change / rotate out.